# PHP XML: Illegal Offset, but it is in array?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

```
$dagen = array(
    'Mon' => 'Maandag',
    'Tue' => 'Dinsdag',
    'Wed' => 'Woensdag',
    'Thu' => 'Donderdag',
    'Fri' => 'Vrijdag',
    'Sat' => 'Zaterdag',
    'Sun' => 'Zondag'
);

foreach ($xml->verwachtingen->verwachting as $verwachting) {
    $graden = $verwachting->maxtempGRC - $verwachting->mintempGRC;
    $graden = $graden / 2;
    $graden = $graden + $verwachting->mintempGRC;
    $dag = $verwachting->dagvdweek;

    echo 'Op '. $dagen[$dag] .' wordt het '. $graden .' graden';
}
```

$xml is the XML document loaded using SimpleXMLElement.

Now, help me out here. When i echo `$dag` it displays 'Fri' because it is Friday. So i try to convert the english words of the days to my language (dutch). But it doesn't seem to work, because i get this:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\data\home\www\awnl-xml\index.php on line 21
Op wordt het 18.5 graden
Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\data\home\www\awnl-xml\index.php on line 21
Op wordt het 18 graden
Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\data\home\www\awnl-xml\index.php on line 21
...
```

Does someone know why i get this error? Thanks.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($dag)`. You'll probably find that it's actually an object, which can't be used as an array index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$dag` will be an object, of type `SimpleXMLElement`. Objects are not allowed to be used for array keys, which is why you are getting that "Illegal offset type" warning.

The object must first be cast to a suitable type before being used like that, in your case it should be a string.

```
$dag = (string) $verwachting->dagvdweek;
```

Comment: Pancakes with loads of sugar for you my friend. Thanks!

Comment: Yay! I'll bring the lemon juice.

Comment: oh php; sometimes things you do elude me.